# GetEnumSelectList The Delegate Type Could Not Be Inferred

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am using an enum to populate a select list. In the view, there is the red line underneath this line.

```
GetEnumSelectList
```

The error says

```
The Delegate Type Could Not Be Inferred
```

Despite that, the app compiles, the select list works, and the app runs ok. Any ideas on how to resolve this error?

View

```
<select asp-for="Level" asp-items="@Html.GetEnumSelectList<Level>()">
   <option>Select Level...</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same issue and found that adding brackets around the method call got rid of the warning, try:

```
<select asp-for="Level" asp-items="@(Html.GetEnumSelectList<Level>())">
   <option>Select Level...</option>
</select>
```